# Contribute to the Docky Project

Tags: docky

I've recently installed Docky and it seems to be a great app to have and I'd like to contribute, or set up custom applets. Is there any guide regarding this? Especially the language used and the format that needs to be followed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out Docky's LaunchPad here :

https://launchpad.net/docky

Seems the best way forward for you would to be either join #docky on irc.freenode.net or speak to one of the developers directly.